# I am not able to start MongoDB ON WINDOWS 10

Tags: mongodb

Mongod is not starting on windows 10 it shows 'access control is not enabled for the database. Read and write access to data and configuration is unrestr 10.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Please don't paste images, use formatted text. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3027266

Answer (score 1):

Mongo is started and is running. This message is simply a notice, not an error. It says that your Mongo database is insecure because anyone is able to read and write. This is fine for your development purposes on your computer, but you should change the settings if you use Mongo for a production, customer-facing website.